# USB devices not being detected

Tags: drivers, 18.04, usb, external-hdd

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.2 LTS and this problem arose. Ubuntu doesn't seem to recognize USB devices through ANY of the 3 hubs that I have on my laptop.

Here's the output of `lsusb` when the USB external HDD is not plugged in:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The output is the same when it is plugged in. I've tried connecting my Android device as well but it gets me the same results.

I've successfully connected my Android device as well as the external HDD to another computer of mine and both of them work completely fine.

Is this a drivers issue?

Comment: What computer are you using? (Desktop? Laptop? Make and model?) What happens when you boot using an old kernel? Output of `dmesg` after plugging in a USB device?

Comment: @xiota, I am using a Dell Inspiron 3558(laptop). I haven't tried booting with an old kernel. So here's what I did, I wiped the 
`dmesg` logs using `sudo demsg -c` and then plugged the HDD in. The thing is, `dmesg` shows *nothing* after plugging it in.

Comment: Try booting the old kernel. If USB works, it's a problem with the kernel.

Comment: Can you recommend me a kernel version? I don't remember the kernel I version that was working before the upgrade.

Comment: According to [Kernel/Support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support), Ubuntu 16.04 uses kernel 4.4. If it's not in the repository, you can find debs at [kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?P=*v[45].*.*&O=D&F=1). If 4.4.x works, you can try each of the longterm releases, 4.9.x, 4.14.x, 4.19.x, as listed at [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/).